# Use post as category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I created two kind of custom post type: "Fields" and "Functions". Can I associate a post field with some function post (like if function was a category).

I choose to use "Functions" as post, cause in its page there are many content (picture, video and text). "Function" works like category, but have content like a post.

I hope I was enough clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, no, you can't treat a post like a category and associate other posts with it.

It sounds like you created this second custom post type because you wanted to associate content with each 'category post'.

If I understand your needs correctly, I think you'll be better served by registering that second post type as a custom taxonomy instead. The registration process is similar as that for post types: if you're doing it in code you can use the register_taxonomy function (see the Codex at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy for documentation) or there are many plugins that will let you do it as well.

As for associating content with your custom taxonomy, I think what you might be looking for here is a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields which, among other things, allows you to add custom fields to a taxonomy term - so you can still associate WYSIWYG content, images, text fields, etc etc.

Trust this solves the issue you have - but if it doesn't, perhaps you could outline more what you are trying to achieve with the solution you proposed?

Comment: Yes, you understood well. It's a more logic solution.